# Deploying AWS Lambda with Go & Cloudformation

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I'm working through an automated deployment of a Go-based AWS Lambda, and having issues.

My AWS Serverless template is:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  HelloLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: hello
      Runtime: go1.x
      CodeUri: ./deploy/hello.zip
      Environment:
        Variables: 
          S3_BUCKET: hello_lambda
```

I deploy this via:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o ./deploy/hello
zip ./deploy/hello.zip ./deploy/hello
aws cloudformation package \
   --template-file hello.yaml \
   --output-template-file serverless-deploy_hello.yaml \
   --s3-bucket hello_deploy
aws cloudformation deploy\
 --template-file serverless-deploy_hello.yaml\
  --stack-name hello-lambda\
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

When Cloudformation does its thing, `serverless-deploy_hello.yaml` has `CodeUri: s3://hello_deploy/17ab86653aab79eee51fc6f77d7a152e` and that s3 bucket contains the zip file (when I download it locally & use `cmp` it's bit-identical).

BUT when I test the resulting Lambda, it gives me:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/hello: no such file or directory",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here....

==== RESOLVED ====

The zip command above zips the directory path as well, so the executable unzips to `deploy/hello` rather than `./hello`.

Accordingly, the Lambda runtime can't connect to the process.

Comment: Can you please check while extracting the zip, if it creates an additional folder? something like var/task/hello/hello". This can be possible cause. But you said that while downloading it locally, it creates the same exact path. Just a hunch maybe.

Comment: well, that was an issue with one of the zip files, but the one I'm uploading now only contains the `hello` executable. Weird.

Comment: Nope, that was exactly the issue - was looking at the wrong zip

Comment: been there.. :P

Answer (score 15):

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/hello: no such file or directory",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

This will look for the hello function in your zipfile as an starting point of the Application. If you want to continue with the main function or some other function

```
func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleLambdaEvent)
}
```

You need to change the handler Name on AWS Lambda function template (By default it is hello).
[image]

Comment: 2020: To change the Handler name go to the 'Basic settings' pane